# Couchbase- How to query view using the C API - libcouchbase

Tags: c, nosql, couchbase

In couchbase official documentation - 
http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-sdk-c-2.0/api-reference-view.html

There is an example of retrieving data from couchbase using views.

```
const char path[] = "myview?startkey=I,endkey=j";
libcouchbase_make_couch_request(instance, NULL, path, npath
                                NULL, 0, LIBCOUCHBASE_HTTP_METHOD_GET, 1);
```

I have downloaded and installed libcouchbase v 2.0.6

It seems there is no function libcouchbase_make_couch_request() or lcb_make_couch_request () available in the library.

Where am I wrong ?

Also it will help a lot if there is an example available somwhere for extracting data which is retrieved after we call the equivalent of libcouchbase_make_couch_request()

Comment: There is no libcouchbase tag in SO - Can anyone create it

Comment: The docs don't seem to match the source. There are a number of examples and the full source here: https://github.com/couchbase/libcouchbase/tree/master/example

Comment: I'm not sure there is enough traffic in the Couchbase tag to warrant creating a tag for just their C API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library itself comes with manpages, which are the most actual documentation. The index page is `man 3 libcouchbase`. The page you need is `man 3 lcb_make_http_request`. Also you can found docs in asciidoc format in the repo itself https://github.com/couchbase/libcouchbase/blob/master/man/man3couchbase/lcb_make_http_request.3couchbase.txt

Between 1.x and 2.x releases, we've changed API a lot, so that it isn't backward compatible mostly. And function `libcouchbase_make_couch_request` was only accessible in "developer preview" version (like beta), eventually it was named `lcb_make_http_request`, because you can use the same call to create design documents, and also perform admin tasks, like create/flush/delete bucket, etc.

Here is the code example from man page above:

```
lcb_http_request_t req;
lcb_http_cmd_t *cmd = calloc(1, sizeof(lcb_http_cmd_t));
cmd->version = 0;
cmd->v.v0.path = "_design/test/_view/all?limit=10";
cmd->v.v0.npath = strlen(item->v.v0.path);
cmd->v.v0.body = NULL;
cmd->v.v0.nbody = 0;
cmd->v.v0.method = LCB_HTTP_METHOD_GET;
cmd->v.v0.chunked = 1;
cmd->v.v0.content_type = "application/json";
lcb_error_t err = lcb_make_http_request(instance, NULL,
                                        LCB_HTTP_TYPE_VIEW,
                                        &cmd, &req);
if (err != LCB_SUCCESS) {
    ... failed to schedule request ...
```

Comment: regarding your comment "The library itself comes with manpages, which are the most actual 'documentation. The index page is man 3 libcouchbase" -  I installed libcouchbase in RHEL5.5. In this box the man pages didnt get installed , man 3 libcouchbase or man libcouchbase or apropos libcouchbase is not working. Do I have to do anything extra to get man pages installed along with the library ?

Comment: They should be installed with libcouchbase-devel package, if not, then it is a bug